# Local build not rendering as expected (links broken)

Tags: blogdown

The `blogdown` book suggests that [local preview](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/local-preview.html) works using

```
blogdown::build_site(local=TRUE)
```

If I understand this correctly, this is supposed to temporarily change the `config.toml` file to set the `baseurl` to `/` thus overwriting whatever setting you have. When I try that, however, it doesn't really work and it keeps showing the original `baseurl` in the resulting `public` folder.

Is there a way to create a "local" version of the resulting site that would keep the links (or most of them, anyway) correct (rather than pointing to the `baseurl` and the online version, which works perfectly, BTW)?

I have seen some posts suggesting that some themes may not be suitable to do that as the authors may have not written the original code to point to `relativeurls` (I know I'm being vague here, but I think it goes to that effect), but is there a way around it?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but the documentation at https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/local-preview.html is currently outdated. I'll update it soon, and post an answer later (unless someone else does it before me). Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Thank you @YihuiXie and no need to apologise of course :-) Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible with [the dev version of **blogdown**](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown) now:

```r
remotes::install_github('rstudio/blogdown')
```

Then restart R, and run:

```r
blogdown::build_site(baseURL = '/')
```

This should temporarily override the `baseURL` setting in your config file. Similarly, you can try to build the site with `relativeURLs = true`:

```r
blogdown::build_site(relativeURLs = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you @YihuiXie! This works now. I wanted to use this to give a copy of the `public` folder to my students, so they can use it offline. The links are now all working, though the automatic redirect from `site/folder` to `site/folder/index.html` of course doesn't work anymore... I may work them manually, though --- I don't think there's an automated way to do this (short of "serving" the site locally in some way)? Thanks again for fixing this so promptly!

Comment: Without a web server, that's not possible. I could at most offer is `servr::httd()`, which is a  pure R function that doesn't rely on Hugo. If your students have R installed, they can run this function in the site folder.

Comment: Thanks again --- I'll check this out! Much appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Anyway to make the "automatic redirect from site/folder to site/folder/index.html" to work?

I think `uglyURLs: true` is supposed to do that (not redirecting, but changing the link to the latter form.

Seems not to always work, though.